# Adding UIImageView to rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

All I am simply trying to do is display an image on the screen as I am just starting out iOS 
development.  I figured since `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, I would add it in a similar way but I am not having any luck. I understand this is an easy question but any help would be appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:                 (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
    UIImage* stallion = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stallion1.png"];

    UIImageView* iv = [UIImageView alloc];
    iv.image = stallion;
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:iv];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Your imageview is named `stallion` but you're setting in `UIImageView` as `iv.image = marsTiled`. Am I missing something?

Comment: yea you are right. I was trying something different when my original try didnt work and i forgot to change that one part. It is correct now

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `viewDidLoad`? My iOS programming skills are little rusty. Check this [tutorial](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/23/tutorial-all-about-images-part-1-uimage-uiimageview/).

Comment: You should call init on the UIImageView

Comment: @rocky Yep, great point. Initialization is needed after allocation. +1.

Comment: And you need to set a frame for UIImageView

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

App delegate:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //allocate and initialize the root view controller
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

    //set the root view controller
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Create a subclass of UIViewController called RootViewController

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//set the class RootViewController as a subcalss of UIViewController
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

.m

```
//this is one of the life cycle methods of a UIViewController and should already be in the code when the class is created
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //execute the viewDidLoad method of the superclass (UIViewController)
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //allocate and initialize the image view 
    //assign the image view a frame
         //x offset from the left = 0.0
         //y offset from the top = 0.0
         //width = the view controller's view's width (should be the whole screen)
         //height = the view controller's view's height(should be the whole screen)
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [iv setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName.png"]];

    //the background will be red if everything is setup correctly, but the image isn't found
    [iv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    //add the image view to the view controller's view 
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
}
```

Comment: I copy and pasted that into my appDelegate.m file and still have a blank screen showing when i run it.

Comment: I am using an empty application project file.  I don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: diabolical.  Alright, doing everything in the app delegate isn't a very good idea.  Let me throw together an example with it broken out.

Comment: You may want to break out the image assignment and set a break point there.  Then you can make sure the image is being found okay.

Comment: the image is being found ok because I took it out of my folder and I got a build error.  So I know it is finding it correctly.

Comment: For `PNG` files, you don't need the extension. @ddelnano have you verified that your file name matches the string EXACTLY (case matters!)?

Comment: Are png extensions optional or are you not supposed to have them?

Comment: Yes it is an exact match. the image is titled "stallion.png"

Comment: @JeffCompton I tried that and I still get a blank screen.  I have this book I'm using and its obviously not teaching me the right things.  Where would I be able to find more information to understand the code above.

Comment: I added some comments and one line of code.  Hopefully that helps.  As for learning iOS, I suggest getting very familiar with delegation.  Almost everything in iOS is done with delegation.  Once you grasp that, everything will make a lot more sense.  I think you're on the right route be starting with easy projects.  Keep coding.  If you ever get stuck, you'll find a ton of people that will be very willing to help on stackoverflow, reddit, etc..

Answer (score 0):

**//EDIT**

It would be very helpful for you if u will read book in which there are information about View Controllers. This is very essential information. I recommend you to read "The Core IOS 6 Cookbook" by Erica Sadum. It really helped me.

You can also just look at the apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/

Write something like this in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Next you must add the UIImageView but only when the view of the created view controller is loaded. The best method for this is viewDidLoad. You can also use viewDidAppear: or viewWillAppear:.
You must override this methods in MyViewController class (which should inherit from the UIViewController class).

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.heigth);
  imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed@"stallion1.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: I'd probably move this to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I'm working in iOS 7 and have had issues with items being sized appropriately when I ask for frame dimensions in `viewDidLoad`. Also, an easier way to get the frame you're after would be: `[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];`.

Comment: I keep getting an error in the code above on the [self addSubview:imageView];

Comment: "No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'addSubview'."

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:imageView];` Try that instead.

Comment: @SimonGerman is right. I didn't notice that mistake. Code have beed edited. Also look at the beginning of my post.